# hot to center and properly position html elements on resizing?

Tags: html, css, web, resize, positioning

ok, what I want to do is pretty complex and I am having a lot of difficulty. I find HTML is so difficult to get looking just right and makes no sense!

I am trying to do a profile page, with a user image, name and a button.
here is my code:

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color:yellow">
<div style="display:inline-block;height:140px;width:140px;background-color:red"></div>
<label> <b> User Name</b> </label>
<button style="float:right">add friend</button>
</div>
```

so, I have 2 issues:

#1: I want the button to be on the right side of the screen, but on the same line as the text for the label saying "Name".

#2: I want to be able to resize the screen and have the elements reposition properly. when there is no room for them, I want them to go underneath each other and become centered. here is and image example:

[image]

is it possible to do this with html and css alone? do need to check the window size with javascript and reposition elements? If so, can I at least get the float right element to position properly with HTML?

any help is appreciated! thank you!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_profile_card.asp check this it will help you. You can also search flexbox

Comment: no this is not what i want.  everything is on top of one another. I want them side by side and only centered and on top when there is no room...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend CSS flexbox for doing this. Its great for doing responsive designs.
To solve your problem easier, i moved the CSS in an external file.

My CSS:

```
.container {
   background-color: yellow;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: end;
}
      
#square {
   display: inline-block;
   height: 140px;
   width: 140px;
   background-color: red;
}

#button {
   margin-left: auto;
}

/* When the screen width is for example smaller than 300px,
collapse the Elemente and show them centered & below each other.
That's how we use the @media keyword. 
Please replace the 300px with your needed size. */

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
   .container {
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
   }

   #button {
     margin-left: 0;
   }
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="square"></div>
   <label>
      <b>User Name</b>
   </label>
   <button id="button">add friend</button>
</div>
```

Learn more about CSS Flexbox:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: i noticed flexbox does not work on older browsers tho. I was wondering if there was a way to do this, that would work on older browsers also?

Comment: also, the example you showed does not do what Im look for. the "button" needs to be on the right side of the screen. so align right, not stuck to the text...

Comment: I think flexbox is the best approach for this, and this is a perfect example for when we use it. It should work in all modern browsers.

Comment: Oh yeah i noticed it. You can solve it by adding `margin-left: auto;` to the button. In the @media query, set it to `margin-left: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: red;

}
.body{
  flex: 1;
   justify-content: space-between;
   padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color:yellow">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="container body">
    <label> <b> User Name</b></label>
    <button>add friend</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the easiest way to do this below

```css
.container1 #box {
  display : inline-block;
  width : 70%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container2 {
  width: 100vw ; 
  height:300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /*be placed under each other*/
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1" style="background-color:yellow">
  <div style="display:inline-block;height:140px;width:29%;background-color:red">
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    <label> <b> User Name</b> </label>
    <button style="float:right">add friend</button>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="container2" style="background-color:yellow">
  <div style="display:inline-block;height:140px;width:140px;background-color:red">
  </div>
  <label> <b> User Name</b> </label>
  <button style="float:right">add friend</button>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).